# Doctrine insert table using joined table entities as reference

Tags: sql, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have spent the last day trying to find a solution to a problem that I am having and now turn to you to see if you can offer some advice.

Ill start with the table and then the entity
I have three tables,
table_a
table_b
table_c
each table row has a unique id
table_c contains a reference to table_a_id and to table_b_id
This reference should be unidirectional as table_a and table_b have no need to ever know of table_c's existence.
Also, there is no cascading, if an id from table_a or table_b does not exist, then table_c should not be able to insert a row.

ok, now for entities. (I am going to cut out irrelevant code to keep it short)

Entity A defines table_a

```
/**
* A
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Sample\Bundle\MyBundle\Entity\ARepository")
* @ORM\Table("table_a")
*/
class A
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 *
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;


/**
 * Get id
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 * @param string $name
 * @return A
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 * @return string 
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}
}
```

Entity B defines table_b

```
/**
* B
*
* @ORM\Table("table_b")
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class B
{
/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 * @param string $name
 * @return B
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 * @return string 
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}
}
```

Entity C maps table_c and has many to one relationships with table_a and table_b

```
 /**
 * C
 *
 * @ORM\Table("table_c")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Sample\Bundle\MyBundle\Entity\CRepository")
 */
 class PricesAverage
 {
/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var \Sample\Bundle\MyBundle\Entity\A
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Sample\Bundle\MyBundle\Entity\A", inversedBy="id")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="a_id",unique=false)
 */
private $a;

/**
 * @var \Sample\Bundle\MyBundle\Entity\B
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Sample\Bundle\MyBundle\Entity\B", inversedBy="id")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="b_id",unique=false)
 */
private $b;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @return A
 */
public function getA() {
    return $this->a;
}

/**
 * @param A $a
 * @return $this
 */
public function setA($a) {
    $this->a = $a;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return B
 */
public function getB() {
    return $this->b;
}

/**
 * @param B $b
 * @return $this
 */
public function setB($b) {
    $this->b = $b;
    return $this;
}
}
```

No what I do is the following. (this is just simplified logic but it is the same process)

```
$days = 5;
$aCollection = {get collection of A's)

for($i = 0,$i<$days,$i++){
    foreach($aCollection as $a){
        $b = {get a single b}
        $c = new C();
        $c->setA($a)
          ->setB($b);
        {use doctrine to persist and flush $c}      
    }
}
```

What is happening is that on the first insert the id for a is correct, but on the second insert, doctrine seems to think that competitor is a new entity and tries to persist and create a new id.

I have dumped my collection without activating the doctrine insert and I see that the id on A is correct, I then do the same thing after doctrine and find that doctrine is somehow clearing away my object.

How can I resolve this?

UPDATE:
I resolved this issue.

The problem that I was having is that the related entity was being removed from the entity manager after I did my batch insert.

The was a result of doing clear after every flush.

I moved clear to the end of the process so I flush as much as I need but only clear once.

Comment: If your table c don't have any extra fields except only associations from a and b then i can its a many to many relation ship have a look at [*`Many-To-Many, Unidirectional`*](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional)

Comment: There are extra fields on C, I just didnt add them so that I could reduce the size of the post

Comment: Have you defined relation OneToMany in your A & B for C(PricesAverage)?

Comment: @herr, No I havent defined that relation as tables a and b are independant of table_c and if table_c were to be removed, no impact should be made on table_a or table_b

Comment: I think the issue may be related to Entity A where I insert the same instance into all of the C's and after the first C is flushed, the A instance is reset and thats why the first insert works, but after that then doctrine assumes a new relation for A